# OpenCv's CMake tooling can't find library 'gio-2.0' (Ubuntu22)?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ubuntu-22.04

when I used `CMake` to configure the source code, there was always warning messages, like these:

```
-- ADE: Downloading v0.1.2b.zip from https://github.com/opencv/ade/archive/v0.1.2b.zip
-- Checking for module 'gtk+-3.0'
--   Found gtk+-3.0, version 3.24.33
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:885 (message):
  ocv_check_modules(GTK3): can't find library 'gio-2.0'.  Specify
  'pkgcfg_lib_GTK3_gio-2.0' manually
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/highgui/cmake/detect_gtk.cmake:5 (ocv_check_modules)
  modules/highgui/cmake/init.cmake:35 (include)
  modules/highgui/cmake/init.cmake:39 (add_backend)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:298 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:361 (_add_modules_1)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:408 (ocv_glob_modules)
  CMakeLists.txt:965 (ocv_register_modules)


-- Checking for module 'gtk+-2.0'
--   Found gtk+-2.0, version 2.24.33
CMake Warning at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:885 (message):
  ocv_check_modules(GTK2): can't find library 'gio-2.0'.  Specify
  'pkgcfg_lib_GTK2_gio-2.0' manually
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  modules/highgui/cmake/detect_gtk.cmake:12 (ocv_check_modules)
  modules/highgui/cmake/init.cmake:35 (include)
  modules/highgui/cmake/init.cmake:39 (add_backend)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:298 (include)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:361 (_add_modules_1)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:408 (ocv_glob_modules)
  CMakeLists.txt:965 (ocv_register_modules)
```

so that I can't compile the target `opencv_highgui` with the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0: No such file or directory  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/build.make:163: lib/libopencv_highgui.so.4.8.0] Error 1 
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5555: modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
```

And the following are the info about my `gtk+-3.0`

```
malloc@mubuntu:build$ pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0
3.24.33
```

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0
-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lharfbuzz -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

Can someone give me a hand?

**UPDATE**

when I use `gcc -o Helloworld helloworld.c pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` to test if the `GTK3` works, there was something error.

```bash
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try `ldd /home/malloc/anaconda3/lib/libgio-2.0.so` what do you see?

Comment: Please don't ask questions in comments.